# PySimpleGUI Adjust SCREEN size

Tags: python, pysimplegui, screen-size

When executing my second layout, it starts with the window off the screen, not being able to close it by the button and cutting the elements displayed according to the print. I would like to know how I leave the screen with a vertical bar or something to be able to use the screen. I'm making this program to train python

Code:

```
from os import system
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from IPython.display import display

##############################DAQUI PRA BAIXO Busca o arquivo excel

#criando layout

layout = [[sg.Text('Busca de arquivo')],      #texto simple     
          [sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse('Buscar')],   #campo input e campo de busca
          [sg.OK(), sg.Cancel('Cancelar')]] #botões ok e cancelar

#gerando a janela
window = sg.Window('Busca de arquivos', layout, resizable=True)

#verificando eventos que ocorre na janela
while True:
    #criando as variaveis que pega os eventos e valores
    event, values = window.read()
    #checando os eventos
    #se clicar pra fechar ele da um break
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':
        break
    #se for ok cria a variavel global com o caminho do arquivo selecionado
    if event == "OK":
        global caminho #cria a variavel global com o caminho do arquivo
        print(values[0])
        caminho = values[0] #coloca o caminho do arquivo na variavel | values devolve um dicionario e precisamos so do 0
        break

#fechando a janela
window.close()

##############################DAQUI PRA BAIXO Le os dados do Excel

arquivo_excel = caminho

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) #Exibe o número máximo de colunas
pd.set_option('display.max_row', None) #Exibe o número máximo de linha
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None) #Exibe o número máximo do tamanha das colunas

data_frame = pd.read_excel(arquivo_excel)

df = data_frame.loc[:,"Nome":"Outros problemas encontrados."]

'''
for x in df["Nome"]:
    print(x)
'''

#df = df.groupby(["Nome"]).agg(list) #agrupa pela coluna nome




nomes = df['Nome']
titulo= df['Título da Demanda']
nome_arquivo = df['Nome do Arquivo']
seq_test = df['Seq. Teste']
q1 = df['Verificar o Nome e Local do Arquivo.']
q2 = df['Verificar se as informações padrão estão sendo exibidas no topo da tela.']
q3 = df['Verificar o "Título do Programa" nas Janelas.']
q4 = df['Verificar se existem erros de ortografia no programa.']
q5 = df['Verificar se os itens estão Subclassificados.']
q6 = df['Verificar se a linha do registro atual está destacada em vermelho.']
q7 = df['Verificar se foi disponibilizada barra de rolagem.']
q8 = df['Verificar as LOVs do programa.']
q9 = df['Verificar o gatilho WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM dos campos com LOV.']
q10 = df['Verificar o alinhamento dos campos na tela.']
q11 = df['Verificar a permissão de inserir, alterar e excluir.']
q12 = df['Verificar a máscara dos campos.']
q13 = df['Verificar o tamanho máximo dos campos carregados por LOV.']
q14 = df['Verificar a ordem dos campos na tela.']
q15 = df['Verificar o preenchimento de campos obrigatórios em telas de Cadastro.']
q16 = df['Verificar a funcionalidade de consulta (F7 e F8) em blocos de banco de dados.']
q17 = df['Verificar o gatilho POST-QUERY dos blocos de banco de dados.']
q18 = df['Verificar as caixas de diálogo do programa.']
q19 = df['Verificar as TABs do programa.']
q20 = df['Verificar abreviatura de informações exibidas ao usuário.']
q21 = df['Outros problemas encontrados.']

'''
print()
print()
print(nomes)
print('titulo: ',titulo[0])
print('Nome arquivo: ',nome_arquivo[0])
print('Sq_teste: ',seq_test[0])
print(q1)
print(q2)
print(q3)
print(q4)
print(q5)
print(q6)
print(q7)
print(q8)
print(q9)
print(q10)
print(q11)
print(q12)
print(q13)
print(q14)
print(q15)
print(q16)
print(q17)
print(q18)
print(q19)
print(q20)
print(q21)
print()
print()
print('------------'*8)
'''

#print(data_frame.loc[:,'Nome'])

#layout = [[sg.Listbox(values=['Listbox 1', 'Listbox 2', 'Listbox 3'], size=(30, 6))]]
#layout = [[sg.Multiline('This is what a Multi-line Text Element looks like', size=(45,5))]] 
layout2 = [ 
    [sg.Text('Título: '),sg.InputText(titulo[0]),sg.Text('Nome do Arquivo: '),sg.InputText(nome_arquivo[0]),sg.Text('Seq. test: '),sg.InputText(seq_test[0])],#TOPO
    [sg.Text()],

    [sg.Text('Usuário: '),sg.InputText(nomes[0])], #PRIMEIRO USUSARIO
    [sg.Text('Verificar o Nome e Local do Arquivo.'                                             ),sg.Multiline(q1[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar se as informações padrão estão sendo exibidas no topo da tela.'         ),sg.Multiline(q2[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar o "Título do Programa" nas Janelas.'                                    ),sg.Multiline(q3[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar se existem erros de ortografia no programa.'                            ),sg.Multiline(q4[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar se os itens estão Subclassificados.'                                    ),sg.Multiline(q5[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar se a linha do registro atual está destacada em vermelho.'               ),sg.Multiline(q6[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar se foi disponibilizada barra de rolagem.'                               ),sg.Multiline(q7[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar as LOVs do programa.'                                                   ),sg.Multiline(q8[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar o gatilho WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM dos campos com LOV.'                       ),sg.Multiline(q9[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar o alinhamento dos campos na tela.'                                      ),sg.Multiline(q10[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar a permissão de inserir, alterar e excluir.'                             ),sg.Multiline(q11[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar a máscara dos campos.'                                                  ),sg.Multiline(q12[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar o tamanho máximo dos campos carregados por LOV.'                        ),sg.Multiline(q13[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar a ordem dos campos na tela.'                                            ),sg.Multiline(q14[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar o preenchimento de campos obrigatórios em telas de Cadastro.'           ),sg.Multiline(q15[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar a funcionalidade de consulta (F7 e F8) em blocos de banco de dados.'    ),sg.Multiline(q16[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar o gatilho POST-QUERY dos blocos de banco de dados.'                     ),sg.Multiline(q17[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar as caixas de diálogo do programa.'                                      ),sg.Multiline(q18[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar as TABs do programa.'                                                   ),sg.Multiline(q19[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Verificar abreviatura de informações exibidas ao usuário.'                        ),sg.Multiline(q20[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text('Outros problemas encontrados.'                                                    ),sg.Multiline(q21[0], size=(130,2))],
    [sg.Text()],

    [sg.Text('Usuário: '),sg.InputText(nomes[1])],#SEGUDO USUÁRIO
    [sg.Text()],

    [sg.Text('Usuário: '),sg.InputText(nomes[2])],#TERCEITO USUÁRIO
    [sg.Text()],

    [sg.Text('Usuário: '),sg.InputText(nomes[3])],#QUARTO USUÁRIO
    [sg.Text()],

    [sg.Text('Usuário: '),sg.OK(), sg.Cancel('Cancelar')] #botões ok e cancelar
    
]


#gerando a janela
window = sg.Window('Editor de informções', layout2)

#verificando eventos que ocorre na janela
while True:
    #criando as variaveis que pega os eventos e valores
    event, values = window.read()
    #checando os eventos
    #se clicar pra fechar ele da um break
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancelar' or event == 'Cancel':
        break
    #se for ok cria a variavel global com o caminho do arquivo selecionado
    if event == "OK":
        break

#fechando a janela
window.close()
#'''
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: If any the width or height of a window is greater than it of the screen, the window will be not located at a good place to show the window. You can use `CTRL + Mouse button 1` to move the screen. You can put your layout into a Column element with options `scrollable=True,  vertical_scroll_only=True, size_subsample_width=m, size_subsample_height=n` for fit your layout into your screen.

Comment: Is it possible to put a vertical bar in the window?

Comment: Do you mean the vertical scrollbar for layout2 ?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the space occupied by your layout greater than screen, you can use `Column` element with scrollbar to limit the space occupied.

Here, option `size_subsample_height` determines the size of a scrollable height based on 1/size_subsample * required size. 1 = match the contents exactly, 2 = 1/2 contents size, 3 = 1/3. Can be a fraction to make larger than required.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

column_layout = [[sg.Text(f'Line {i+1:0>3d}'), sg.Input()] for i in range(100)]
layout = [[sg.Column(column_layout, scrollable=True,  vertical_scroll_only=True, size_subsample_height=5)]]
sg.Window('Title', layout).read(close=True)
```